# How to run this command in CMD Windows

Tags: mysql, password-management, cmd.exe, syntax

I' am not an expert in CMD. I want to reset my MySQL Database password. I saw articles online which only says to run the following command

```
 C:\\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld-nt --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

I executed the command, but it was not executed successfully. How can I execute this command?

Comment: I think you just need to add double quotes to your path. "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld-nt" --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt should work. Also, remove the double backslashes

Comment: @Chirag64 pretty much what I thought too, but also notice there is no executable being called.

Comment: @AthomSfere I think mysqld-nt is the executable. Command prompt does not need you to add the .exe extension in most cases.

Comment: @Chirag64 Yep, you are right. Binged it (replaced my Google for now) and confirmed thats the .exe. Editing answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny looking command, and It doesn't look right...

If you are running with out CDing into the bin folder, try:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld-nt.exe" --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt
```

First, you might try using the executable name as .exe Second, `\\` is generally used for UNC paths, I don't see why you need those in the command so use just `\` unless you are calling from something that would escape the first `\` like C#.

Finally, wrap the path to the exe in "" to make sure it doesn't split the path on spaces.